# how to do a iterative rollup in sql

Tags: sql, iteration, rollup

Hi I want to do a rolling sum (of valx) based on previous row value of rolling sum(valy) and the current row value of valx

valy=previousrow_valy + valx

```
animal valx valy 
cat    1    1 
cat    3    4 
cat    2    6 
dog    4    4 
dog    6    10 
dog    7    17 
dog    8    25
```

Answer (score 1):

You should define an order here.

Assuming you want to order by `somecolumn`.

In `Oracle` and `PostgreSQL 8.4`:

```
SELECT  animal, valx, SUM(valx) OVER (PARTITION BY animal ORDER BY somecolumn) AS valy
FROM    mytable
```

In `MySQL`:

```
SELECT  animal, valx,
        @valy := CASE WHEN @animal = animal THEN @valy + valx ELSE valx END AS valy,
        @animal := animal
FROM    (
        SELECT  @valy = 0,
                @animal := NULL
        ) vars,
        mytable
ORDER BY
        animal, somecolumn
```

In `SQL Server`, it is one of the rare cases when creating a `CURSOR` is more efficient.

All databases (including `SQL Server`) support `ANSI` syntax:

```
SELECT  animal, valx,
        (
        SELECT  SUM(valx)
        FROM    mytable mi
        WHERE   mi.animal = mo.animal
                AND mi.somecolumn <= mo.somecolumn
        ) AS valy
FROM    mytable mo
```

, however, this is not efficient if there are many records in `mytable`, execution time grows as `O(n^2)`

Comment: The last query for SQL Server returns exactly the same data as in the input table.

Comment: @Quassnoi Please take a look at my answer when you have a moment to see if you endorse the alternate approach I have provided.  I admire your work on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Brian: how exactly is it alternate?

Comment: @Quassnoi it is using partition by and has no inline view.  The inline view is just to provide sample data so the query is executable as is.

Comment: @Brian: please take a closer look to the first query in the post.